# How to dynamically render Tex and LaTex formulas without refreshing the page using MathJax?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my html as follows:

```html
<textarea id="content"></textarea>
<div id="render"></div>
```

Now I use this javascript to dynamically update any change in the `textarea`:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("content");
const log = document.getElementById("render");
input.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
    log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

I use MathJax official cdn script to convert `Tex` and `LaTex` formulas. The script is working fine and loads the `Tex` and `LaTex` codes as formula while the page loads. But when I type any code inside the `textarea` I just see the same `Tex` or `Latex` code. Eg. If I type `\(\alpha\)` I should probably get the `alpha` symbol while dynamically rendering the contents of the `textarea`, instead I get the same text back. I want to acheive something like [this](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo)  in their mathjax demo page. I think I'm in the half way out there. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `MathJax.Hub.queue` so that whenever you typed anything in input box they are operate by `MathJax` in right order and would queue the command `MathJax.Hub.Typeset("yourdivid")` to typeset the div with id giving .

So,your html code will be look below :

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
//apply config
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
//your cdn for mathjax
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">
</script>
<textarea id="content"></textarea>
<div id="render"></div>
```

And your js code will look like below :

```
const input = document.getElementById("content");
const log = document.getElementById("render");
input.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
console.log(e.target.value)
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
  //adding in queue 
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "render"]);
}
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/pxLegc2o/1/

Comment: Is there any similar approaches of avoiding the usage on `const`. Omitting `const input = document.getElementById("content");
const log = document.getElementById("render");` this line `document.getElementById("content").addEventListener("input", updateValue);` worked. But `document.getElementById("render").textContent = e.target.value;` didn't work.

Comment: Since my page has django loops, I want to use the same script for multiple elements

Comment: use class instead of ids then .also i don't have much knowledge about django it would be good if you can asked another question :)

Comment: That is fine! Seems i have to wrap up with some other alternatives!